# anacondaを再インストールできません

Tags: macos, anaconda

Anacondaを公式サイトからダウンロードした後、こちらのページ
https://weblabo.oscasierra.net/python-anaconda-uninstall-macos/
を参考にしてアンインストールを行いました。

そしてanacondaが必要になったのでもう一度anacondaをダウンロードしようとしたら

```
Anaconda3 is already installed in /opt/anaconda3. Use 'conda update anaconda3' to update Anaconda3.
```

というエラーが返ってきてダウンロードすることができません
optに入ってanaconda3があるかを確認しても何もファイルはなく、conda コマンドも使えない状態です
もう一度anacondaをインストールしたいのですが、どうしたらできるでしょうか
よろしくお願いいたします

使用環境
macOS Catalina バージョン10.15.7

Comment: > もう一度anacondaをダウンロードしようとしたら　　具体的にはどのような手順でしょうか？

Comment: @merino 再ダウンロードも公式サイトから試みました　https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual

Comment: この辺の記事が何か良さそうですが。[Uninstall Anaconda on a Mac](https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-anaconda-on-a-mac), [How to uninstall Anaconda on Mac](https://setapp.com/how-to/uninstall-anaconda-on-mac)

Comment: env | grep によりCONDAに関する環境変数確認してそれらを削除したり、./zshrcの中身のconda部分のpathを消去したりしてからsource コマンドか再起動で変更を反映させます. そして再びダウンロードを開始して、手順のインストール先選択でもう一度「自分専用の場所にインストール」を選択することでうまくダウンロードできました。コメントありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

これまでは.bash_profileにPATHが記入されていましたが、Catalinaの場合.zshrcにPATHが記入されています。そちらのPATHがクリアになっていないのかもしれません。.bash_profileのPATHをクリアにしたのと同様の方法で.zshrcもクリアにしてみてください。