# Anacondaの再インストールができなくて困っています

Tags: macos, anaconda

Anaconda individualをMacBook Air M1にインストールしてPythonの勉強を始めましたが、２週間程してJupyter Notebookが起動しなくなり（File not found)、アンインストール、再インストールを行いました。

アンインストールは以下のページを参考にしました。

[Anaconda3をmacOSから完全にアンインストールする方法](https://weblabo.oscasierra.net/python-anaconda-uninstall-macos/)

---

再インストールしたところ、以下のメッセージが出て、OKをクリックすると「インストールできませんでした。エラーによってインストールできませんでした。ソフトウェアの製造元に問い合わせてください」と表示され終了してしまいます。

```
Anaconda3 is already installed in /opt/anaconda3. Use 'conda update anaconda3' to update Anaconda3.
```

過去の [jpkmさんの質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/72242) と同じ状況なので、`env | grep` で残存ファイルが無いことを確認し、PATHから/opt/anaconda3/binが除かれたことも確認しました。
念の為、Funterでanacondaを探してみましたが、残存ファイルは見つかりませんでした。
その上で再インストールを試しても「Anaconda3 is already〜」となってしまいます。

当方、Excelを使う程度で言語の勉強はFortran、Basic以来です。Macも20年振りくらいのほとんど素人です。
よろしくご教授お願いします。

Comment: Jupyter Notebook の起動はどのように行われたのでしょうか？　また、Anaconda のインストールは最初と 2 回目それぞれどのように行われましたか。

Comment: Jupiter NotebookはAnaconda3をインストール後にターミナルでJupiter notebookを実行して起動させました（Pyhon 「完全」入門　SB Creative）。anacondaのインストールはいずれもanaconda のHPからダウンロードしたインストーラーを起動して行いました。

Comment: @nekketsuuuさん　nacondaがインストールできないので、googleのcollab.researchで提供されるPythonを使っていたところ、知らないうちにanaconda navigatorが立ち上がっており、HOME画面からJupiter notebookをクリックすると立ち上がりました。とりあえず使用できていますが、何が起こったのか、何が問題だったのか全くわかりません。